# Is there a way to access internal metastore of Azure HDInsight to fire queries on Hive metastore tables?

Tags: azure, hive, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to access the internal Hive metastore tables like HIVE.SDS, HIVE.TBLS etc.
I have an HDInsight Hadoop Cluster running with the default internal metastore. From Ambari screen, I got the Advanced setting details required for connections like -
`javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName,javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL,javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName` as well as the password

When I try connecting to the SQL Server instance(internal hive metastore) instance from a local machine, I get the message to add my IP address to the allowed list. However, since this Azure SQL server is not visible in the list of Azure SQL server dbs in the portal, it is not possible for me to whitelist my IP.

So, I tried logging in via the secure shell user- SSHUSER into the Cluster and tried accessing the HIVE database from within the Cluster using the credentials of metastore provided in Ambari. I am still not able to access it. I am using sqlcmd to connect to sql sever.
Does HDInsight **prevent** direct access to internal Metastores? Is External Metastore the only way to move ahead? Any leads would be helpful.

Update- I created an external SQL Server instance and used it as an external metastore and was able to access it programatically.
No luck with the Internal one yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to access internal metastores for HDInsight cluster.  The internal metastores live in the internal subscription which only PGs are able to access.

If you want to have more control on you metastores it is recommended to bring your own "external" metastore.

Comment: Pardon me, what are PG's? Yes, seems like they have prevented direct access to internal metastore, though it beats me as to how providing read-only access to an underlying SQL database could be a security concern.